# Why Does Access Return Different ResultSet When Query Run Programmatically?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've written a query in MS Access. This is a simplified version:

```
SELECT IIf([category] LIKE "*abc*","DEF",category) AS category
, Month
, Sum(qty) AS [qty] 
FROM [tableX] 
GROUP BY category, Month
```

The purpose of the query is to sum quantities of a product in different categories for different months. I want to aggregate categories like abc into a single category called ABC. When I view the query in Access the categories are correctly aggregated, but if I select from the query in C# code no aggregation is done.
Any ideas why this is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard for when using the Access database engine's [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HP030704831033.aspx) is %, not *.

The Access database engine's OLE DB providers (e.g. via ADO classic, ADO.NET, etc) always use ANSI-92 Query Mode.

The Access UI uses ANSI-89 Query Mode by default but can be put into ANSI-92 Query Mode.

DAO always uses ANSI-89 Query Mode.

Using the (unsupported) `ALIKE` keyword always uses the '%' wildcard regardless of Query Mode.

Comment: So does ADO directly run the sql behind the query even although it's is saved in the database?

Comment: As far as I know, it is the connection that runs the SQL, even if it is a stored query, so if the connection is ADO, you need %

Comment: Thanks for the additonal info onedaywhen

Answer (score 0):

if it's working in Access so try to make it as a **Query** in Access and use it from your APP.

Comment: I wasn't wanting to change category to uppercase. I've changed the example to make this clear.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand the case, try now.